# Application crashes after when array of images are stored

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm getting the screenshots from the following code:

```
CGImageRef cgScreen = UIGetScreenImage();
    if (cgScreen) {
        UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgScreen];
        CGImageRelease(cgScreen);
        return result;
    }
```

I'm calling the above code in a timer of 1/1.0 seconds as:

```
[array addObject:[UIImage imageWithScreenContents]];
```

where `imagewithScreenContents` is a function.
But after some seconds i.e after adding 90 frames application crashes.
I'm unable to understand the problem.
Can somebody help me in solving the problem.

The following is the crash log report:-
Incident Identifier: C2EE3C76-1467-4578-BCFE-A29C1F0008A6
CrashReporter Key:   66bc0900aa035a62f27c2c26fe3f6f3f1b8e7301
Process:         VideoRecorderProject [98]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/37935917-FB62-48D4-9DF8-AC5D897C137F/VideoRecorderProject.app/VideoRecorderProject
Identifier:      VideoRecorderProject
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  debugserver [97]

Date/Time:       2007-01-08 19:13:52.228 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1.2 (7D11)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x4317b878
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32668ecc 0x32665000 + 16076
1   CoreFoundation                  0x32d83d6a 0x32d4d000 + 224618
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32d4fc28 0x32d4d000 + 11304
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32d83c44 0x32d4d000 + 224324
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32d9cc4c 0x32d4d000 + 326732
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32da81d8 0x32d4d000 + 373208
6   CoreFoundation                  0x32db05fc 0x32d4d000 + 407036
7   VideoRecorderProject            0x000031ca 0x1000 + 8650
8   Foundation                      0x33f36d94 0x33f29000 + 56724
9   CoreFoundation                  0x32da44bc 0x32d4d000 + 357564
10  CoreFoundation                  0x32da3c18 0x32d4d000 + 355352
11  GraphicsServices                0x31bb936c 0x31bb5000 + 17260
12  UIKit                           0x30bf3c28 0x30bf0000 + 15400
13  UIKit                           0x30bf2228 0x30bf0000 + 8744
14  VideoRecorderProject            0x00003010 0x1000 + 8208
15  VideoRecorderProject            0x00002fac 0x1000 + 8108

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3272e4b8 0x3272d000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x32731094 0x3272d000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32da4002 0x32d4d000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32da3c18 0x32d4d000 + 355352
4   WebCore                         0x32f486f0 0x32ec4000 + 542448
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x327587b0 0x3272d000 + 178096

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x327be720 0x3272d000 + 595744
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x327604d8 0x3272d000 + 210136
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3275fc9c 0x3272d000 + 208028
3   CoreMedia                       0x31f78660 0x31f73000 + 22112
4   CoreMedia                       0x31f7853c 0x31f73000 + 21820
5   MediaToolbox                    0x319e5bb4 0x319e2000 + 15284
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x327587b0 0x3272d000 + 178096

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00a44610    r1: 0x3196dff0      r2: 0x01007a00      r3: 0x31972ec8
    r4: 0x38602bf8    r5: 0x0460226c      r6: 0x656a626f      r7: 0x2fffe93c
    r8: 0x3841eff4    r9: 0x0100028a     r10: 0x000000c8     r11: 0x3841eff4
    ip: 0x38414230    sp: 0x2fffe924      lr: 0x32d83d71      pc: 0x32668ecc
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x4a3fff +VideoRecorderProject armv6   /var/mobile/Applications/37935917-FB62-48D4-9DF8-AC5D897C137F/VideoRecorderProject.app/VideoRecorderProject
  0x9a3000 -   0x9a4fff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6  /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
  0x9c0000 -   0x9c1fff  dns.so armv6  <957f94410f77a351749ac39d2b4b4abe> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
  0x9dc000 -   0x9e7fff +WinterBoard.dylib arm  /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/WinterBoard.dylib
  0x9ee000 -   0x9f2fff  libsubstrate.dylib armv6  /usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv6   /usr/lib/dyld
0x301a0000 - 0x301a6fff  MBX2D armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x301c4000 - 0x3037efff  CoreGraphics armv6  <724ca87c683dfc06a7b8de93ad7529ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x303ce000 - 0x3047bfff  WebKit armv6  <0c25498f719543dfe237b3d5ad2b41f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x30566000 - 0x30585fff  Bom armv6  <53d3b28e15e1aef824becf93c177c7c7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3058b000 - 0x305bffff  Security armv6  <9b4c89ffb90e39d912571072fc4571db> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x305c2000 - 0x305c3fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <410c46b0db15595f49443de4b0f96bc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x30a03000 - 0x30a0dfff  libkxld.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x30a53000 - 0x30a54fff  CoreSurface armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x30a55000 - 0x30a93fff  VideoToolbox armv6  <457298c79adc8623fa6ad998f871cd5f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x30ab3000 - 0x30ae7fff  SystemConfiguration armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30afe000 - 0x30b0cfff  libz.1.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x30bf0000 - 0x319e1fff  UIKit armv6  <02702efa29385ec77b4fad6771ea9fea> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x319e2000 - 0x31af8fff  MediaToolbox armv6  <0a04b31799af43bec335c461e1ba1f8d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x31bad000 - 0x31bb4fff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <314f79317c7b3f8ccb5715f50a1c32bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x31bb5000 - 0x31bc0fff  GraphicsServices armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x31bc6000 - 0x31bd2fff  DataAccessExpress armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x31bd3000 - 0x31cc9fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <0c9d767c5ea2052102d5364b731774a4> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x31d27000 - 0x31d33fff  IAP armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x31d34000 - 0x31d3cfff  AccountSettings armv6  <439ef235750de9dd46831e87cc1d47a4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x31d68000 - 0x31e69fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <48d461b0b7e4c3c34fdd8906e43a9c48> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x31f05000 - 0x31f72fff  CFNetwork armv6  <0c45ba25308645c6e0e6a0934c8ecc98> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31f73000 - 0x31fbafff  CoreMedia armv6  <459a316db9a67b3f336d081196b17001> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x31fbb000 - 0x3210ffff  AudioToolbox armv6  <449419ad6f59bbfef367d329152d8466> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32112000 - 0x32114fff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <12376568046badc4c6993e85624671c4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x321cd000 - 0x32228fff  CoreAudio armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x32285000 - 0x322dffff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x322f4000 - 0x322f6fff  AppleJPEG armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x324ab000 - 0x324e5fff  libvDSP.dylib armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32665000 - 0x32708fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <70da12c30a834268531d6fc845833f9b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3272d000 - 0x32853fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x32990000 - 0x329aefff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x329ec000 - 0x32a4dfff  GMM armv6  <0353946f7ed83f41e2fca11040f47a36> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x32a7d000 - 0x32af9fff  AddressBookUI armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x32afa000 - 0x32b1dfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32b3e000 - 0x32b8bfff  IOKit armv6  <0c1722088423026dbc67adb8a83c4b8b> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x32c95000 - 0x32c98fff  MobileInstallation armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x32d4d000 - 0x32df9fff  CoreFoundation armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x32e15000 - 0x32e25fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <050c16b1a6ea7e4e3c80556a2f9c746e> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32e2f000 - 0x32e56fff  AppSupport armv6  <5c2d41e8c22380b938e7a3194adff14e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x32e85000 - 0x32e91fff  CoreVideo armv6  <5ff949c6e178ed567a3516fec7a336fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x32ec4000 - 0x33617fff  WebCore armv6  <7621be5a489bafd9129ec542ee5faf6a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x33624000 - 0x3370bfff  MusicLibrary armv6  <3619add890481e699291fc9eeb08ff16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x3370c000 - 0x33781fff  MediaPlayer armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x337b4000 - 0x33837fff  PhotoLibrary armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PhotoLibrary
0x33838000 - 0x3384afff  TelephonyUI armv6  <4c4bd6cd6e4137c7f0ec4959b3966144> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x3384b000 - 0x33855fff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <976de01a455ee09d192898dc306043e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x33856000 - 0x3385ffff  SpringBoardServices armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33860000 - 0x338cafff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <3fa3413ae26f5e206c8a2ee46fb04bfb> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x338cb000 - 0x338d2fff  MobileMusicPlayer armv6  <34f1d2d3c143e37bcb35d15eee9690f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileMusicPlayer.framework/MobileMusicPlayer
0x338f3000 - 0x3391ffff  CoreLocation armv6  <42ac528bf061b83d5f9247f59be52ab2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x33924000 - 0x3395efff  CoreTelephony armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3395f000 - 0x33963fff  IOSurface armv6  <5eb19b9643e17c51321283ba4a598d22> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x33bd6000 - 0x33bdbfff  ITSync armv6  <69bcae4bd9e96753e063524a636273ce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x33be6000 - 0x33ce3fff  JavaScriptCore armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33ce4000 - 0x33ceffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <428a3247762594db6424083116f0aa6a> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x33cf0000 - 0x33cf0fff  vecLib armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x33d02000 - 0x33d02fff  Accelerate armv6  <21e1dc9fad96f0d51afbeb7f7e006aaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x33d03000 - 0x33d12fff  MobileBluetooth armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x33e57000 - 0x33e75fff  AddressBook armv6  <314d6d5c19d8a41144176a9772aeeb8e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x33e7b000 - 0x33f25fff  QuartzCore armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33f29000 - 0x34021fff  Foundation armv6  <666e9e488f83b9e196aa70a6b44fdc93> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34041000 - 0x34058fff  OpenGLES armv6  <0c5c914ead991e607b89d480e4215fe8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x34059000 - 0x34106fff  ImageIO armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34112000 - 0x3414ffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <50e793fc4b4de6b598be29d591a31f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x34150000 - 0x34152fff  ArtworkCache armv6  <6ed4c29dcdbff2213ce8fa156bd65215> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x34285000 - 0x342d5fff  Celestial armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x342f9000 - 0x34337fff  CoreText armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x34358000 - 0x3435efff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <6fe2483fe67d4fc5c932ae02a64501c2> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3435f000 - 0x34367fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <6673f222acee5f3a208169712387862a> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x343ab000 - 0x343adfff  Camera armv6  <83d973c375886b5c4632beae0cea27c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Camera.framework/Camera

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: You need to show more context and more code. Also, it would help a lot if you include the crash report. What is the actual issue? Are you running out of memory, for example? Is it an access violation?

Answer (score 0):

You must not release the image obtained by `UIGetScreenImage();`. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html) for a detailed explanation. This is most likely the reason for the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.